# Dask adaptive scaling is failing with an error

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to implement Adapative scaling in Dask. But getting the following error in loop.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'
```

Trace

```
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop object at 0x10ab2a0b8>>, <Task finished coro=<AdaptiveCore.adapt() done, defined at /Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py:179> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'")>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 767, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 191, in adapt
    target = await self.safe_target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 129, in safe_target
    n = await self.target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive.py", line 145, in target
    return await self.scheduler.adaptive_target(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop object at 0x10ab2a0b8>>, <Task finished coro=<AdaptiveCore.adapt() done, defined at /Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py:179> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'")>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 767, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 191, in adapt
    target = await self.safe_target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 129, in safe_target
    n = await self.target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive.py", line 145, in target
    return await self.scheduler.adaptive_target(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop object at 0x10ab2a0b8>>, <Task finished coro=<AdaptiveCore.adapt() done, defined at /Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py:179> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'")>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 767, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 191, in adapt
    target = await self.safe_target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 129, in safe_target
    n = await self.target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive.py", line 145, in target
    return await self.scheduler.adaptive_target(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'
tornado.application - ERROR - Exception in callback functools.partial(<bound method IOLoop._discard_future_result of <tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop object at 0x10ab2a0b8>>, <Task finished coro=<AdaptiveCore.adapt() done, defined at /Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py:179> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'")>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 767, in _discard_future_result
    future.result()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 191, in adapt
    target = await self.safe_target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive_core.py", line 129, in safe_target
    n = await self.target()
  File "/Users/jpujari/Documents/sandbox/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/adaptive.py", line 145, in target
    return await self.scheduler.adaptive_target(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adaptive_target'
```

I have a custom cluster class as shown below

```
from distributed.deploy import Cluster
import boto3

class EcsCluster(Cluster):

    def __init__(self, gpu=False):
        # status = 'init'
        self.gpu = gpu
        super().__init__(asynchronous=False)

    def get_cluster_name(self):
        return 'jp-test'

    def get_service_name(self):
        service_name = 'jp-test-gpu-worker-service' if self.gpu else 'jp-test-cpu-worker-service'
        return service_name

    def scale_up(self, no_of_workers):
        try:
          client = boto3.client('ecs')
          response = client.update_service(
              cluster=self.get_cluster_name(),
              service=self.get_service_name(),
              desiredCount=no_of_workers,
          )
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Problem occurred during scale up: {ex}")

    def scale_down(self, no_of_workers=0):
        try:
            client = boto3.client('ecs')
            response = client.update_service(
                cluster=self.get_cluster_name(),
                service=self.get_service_name(),
                desiredCount=no_of_workers,
            )
            print(response)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Problem occurred during scale down: {ex}")
```

And this is the code I am trying to run

```
    from project.distributed.ecscluster import EcsCluster
    from dask.distributed import Client
    cluster = EcsCluster()
    cluster.adapt(minimum=0, maximum=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get adaptive scaling Dask Cluster subclasses need to implement a few attributes. I recommend looking at the Adaptive class for more information.